# Creating a class take takes in 2D arrays(vectors)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am learning c++ and feel like I am messing up a key concept up. I am trying to create a class that takes in 2D arrays and lets me manipulate them with functions down the line. The 2d array will be represented as a vector but I take it in as a generic(class T). I keep getting variables x and y not declared in my class. I would not know these values prior to runtime and tried to assign them a max value of 50. I even tried global variables, but seem to be getting errors saying x is not a type. Any help would be appreciated:

```
using std::vector;

int x  = 50;
int y = 50;

template<class T>
class Graph{
    public:
        Graph(T vec, int x, int  y){
            this -> x = x;
            this -> y = y;
            v = vec;
        }
        void printArray(){
            for(int i = 0; i < x; x++){
                for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                    cout << v[i][j] << " , ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<vector<int>> v(x,y);
        int x,y = 50;
};
```

How would I make a class that takes in 2d arrays of an unknown type so I can create methods to manipulate them?

Comment: `vector<vector<T>> v(x,y);`, and take that as constructor parameter also. And note that keeping a single `std::vector<T>` for storage, while doing the x * y calculation inside your class, will be way more efficient and performant memory wise.

Comment: You can't use "function call" syntax when doing inline initialization. For this case I recommend you use a constructor initializer list: `Graph(...) : v(x, y) { ... }`

Comment: Interesting, I am coming from Java so learning about c++ types is something I have been having trouble wrapping my head around. I probably can't take in a vector, so instead, just make a constructor that takes in the size, and create the vector in the constructor from the passed-in size. To take in input I would create a function within the class to take in input to fill in the array. Does that sound right?

Comment: Better at least.

Comment: fwiw, things like `int x,y = 50;` is one reason to declare only one variable per line.

Comment: you should start by writing the non template class. If it fails for `int` it wont work for `T`.

Comment: Constructiors (and other functions) can take vectors as arguments. But you have to remember that by default arguments in C++ are passed *by value* (meaning their value is copied) instead of by reference as in Java. You need to use the `&` specifier to pass by reference in C++, as in `std::vector<T> const& argument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `x` and `y` are not needed at all for iterating the array. You can rewrite the for-loops as follows:

```
for (auto const& slice : v) {
    for (auto const& element : slice) {
        cout << element << " , ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**Update, 2023-02-06:**

I've rewritten your class example so that it compiles:

```
template<class T>
class Graph{
    public:
        Graph(T vec, int x, int  y){
            this -> x = x;
            this -> y = y;
            v = vec;
        }
        void printArray(){
            for(int i = 0; i < x; x++){
                for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                    cout << v[i][j] << " , ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    private:
        int x,y = 50;
        vector<vector<int>> v;
};
```

You can even omit the variables `x` and `y` completely:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Graph{
    public:
        Graph(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& vec) 
            : v{vec}
        {}
        void printArray(){
            for (auto const& slice : v) {
                for (auto const& element : slice) {
                    cout << element << " , ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<vector<T>> v;
};
```

Comment: I can't believe how long I was stuck on this. Thanks a ton, I learned a lot from your answer!